# SQLITE: Appending string to primary key

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I'm using this to try and name the values in NAME to ValueOLD

```
UPDATE PLAYERS SET NAME = NAME + 'OLD';
```

However I am receiving

```
Execution finished with errors.
Result: UNIQUE constraint failed: PLAYERS.NAME
At line 1:
UPDATE PLAYERS SET NAME = NAME + 'OLD';
```

I've seen some questions asked on inserts that look like they work, but haven't had any success with UPDATE or SET

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `SQLite`, `||` can be used for concatenation.

So Try:

```sql
UPDATE
    PLAYERS
SET
    NAME = NAME || 'OLD';
```

[SQL Language Expressions](https://sqlite.org/lang_expr.html)

> The || operator is "concatenate" - it joins together the two strings
> of its operands.